# ErrorSystem.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80004005): ORA-12504: TNS:listener was not given the SERVICE_NAME in CONNECT_DATA

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a c# project to register a new user in visual studio and using toad for database.The code to conect to database is:

```
protected void New_User(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    OleDbConnection conn;


     OleDbDataAdapter OledbAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            String sql = "";
            conn = new OleDbConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ConnectionString);

            sql = "INSERT INTO USER_DETAIL VALUES('" + TextBoxUN.Text + "','" +TextBoxPass.Text+ "', '" + TextBoxEmail.Text + "','" + TextBoxmobileno.Text +"')";
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                OledbAdapter.InsertCommand = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn);
                OledbAdapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Label_success.Text = "Successfully inserted into database";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Label_success.Text = "Error" + ex.ToString();
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
}
```

and my web.config file is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>

    <!--
      For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
      http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
      -->

    <configuration>
      <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ConnString" connectionString="Provider=MSDAORA;Data Source=TRGDB;Persist Security Info=True;Password=pass;User ID=TRAINEE01" providerName="System.Data.OleDb"/>
        <add name="ApplicationServices"
             connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
      </connectionStrings>

      <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />

        <authentication mode="Forms">
          <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
        </authentication>

        <membership>
          <providers>
            <clear/>
            <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
                 enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
                 maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
                 applicationName="/" />
          </providers>
        </membership>

        <profile>
          <providers>
            <clear/>
            <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
          </providers>
        </profile>

        <roleManager enabled="false">
          <providers>
            <clear/>
            <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
            <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
          </providers>
        </roleManager>

      </system.web>

      <system.webServer>
         <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
      </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

But i am getting the following error:

> ErrorSystem.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80004005): ORA-12504: TNS:listener was not given the SERVICE_NAME in CONNECT_DATA at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString constr, OleDbConnection connection) at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open() at Project._Default.New_User(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\documents and settings\admin\my documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Project\Project\Default.aspx.cs:line 26

Comment: Do not use string concatenation to add values to a SQL statement: parametrise instead. Once you connect to the database you'll be vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Answer (score 0):

Your connectionstring should be like this :

Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MyHost)(PORT=MyPort))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=MyOracleSID)));
User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;

Please refer : http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/